# Authentication Mechanism in Hyperledger Fabric based Web and Mobile application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How to implement User Authentication in Hyperledger Fabric based Web and Mobile application? We know that Fabric CA returns Private key and Certificate on user registration.

1. What are the possible ways of authenticating users in Hyperledger Fabric based Web App?
2. Can we use password based  authentication? If not, how to implement authentication using private key in Web app.
3. How to implement in Android Mobile App? How to secure private key in Android App?

Can someone share sample or pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'll want to have an authentication layer that translates your typical user interactions, via a website or mobile app, into requests to the various Fabric nodes.

What that means is that you'll stand up some sort of api, we'll say it's in nodejs as the nodejs sdk is the most mature. You can set up whatever authentication you want to with that api: password, oauth, jwt, mutual tls, the same way you would with any other api. Now that your users are able to login to your api using whatever auth mechanism you selected, you can write endpoints that your authenticated users can hit that will then make requests to the fabric nodes on their behalf.

Once your api is up and running, you can make whichever front-end you want. Whether that front-end is a website or a mobile app, they'll both login to your api and then make requests to it using that login token.

Most of this is manual, meaning there's no utility that will stand up an api with an auth mechanism that'll make fabric requests for you. There used to be hyperledger composer but that's now defunct. However, you'll need to write your api in either nodejs or golang, which are the two languages with a mature sdk for communicating with fabric nodes.

Comment: Thanks @ajp for your reply. In that case, all Authenticated users would need access to their wallets in order to make requests to fabric nodes. Which type of wallet storage should be used - File system or CouchDB ? How to ensure the security of wallets?

Comment: Typically the users do not have access to their key material directly. The API hosts a wallet, and users then authenticate to the API using conventional methods. For example, you login with a username and password, perform some actions, and then the API submits those actions to the DLT using your key. In this situation, the API hosts must be trusted to be your key host.

File system/couchdb are both fine initially, but the ultimate security would be to have a file system or couchdb wallet + using an HSM to store private keys.